# C++ Cache friendly way of accessing all the members of all elements of a `vector <struct_type>`

Tags: c++, optimization, memory, struct, cache-control

I'm interested in optimizing my code for multithreaded computing. In terms of the cache, pipelining, or any other aspects of memory access, how do the following compare for conserving those resources:

Case 1

```
struct something{
    float a;
    float b;
    int c;
    bool d;
};

vector <something> vec(n, something());

for(int q=0; q<n; q++)
    {
         vec[q].a = expression1;
         vec[q].b = expression2;
         vec[q].c = expression3;
         vec[q].d = expression4;
    }
```

Case 2

```
struct something{
    float a;
    float b;
    int c;
    bool d;
};

vector <something> vec(n, something());

for(int q=0; q<n; q++)
    vec[q].a = expression1;
for(int q=0; q<n; q++)
    vec[q].b = expression2;
for(int q=0; q<n; q++)
    vec[q].c = expression3;
for(int q=0; q<n; q++)
    vec[q].d = expression4;
```

Case 3

```
vector <float> a(n);
vector <float> b(n);
vector <int>   c(n);
vector <bool>  d(n); 

for(int q=0; q<n; q++)
    a[q] = expression1;
for(int q=0; q<n; q++)
    b[q] = expression2;
for(int q=0; q<n; q++)
    c[q] = expression3;
for(int q=0; q<n; q++)
    d[q] = expression4;
```

Also, are there better ways of approaching the above?

Comment: My guess is second is the worst, and third might be the best if you merge 4 `for` loops into one, as in first example. Also, don't forget `vector<bool>` is a specialization, you might not want that.

Comment: @Violet: But that would make it the same as case 2, which is clearly worst in terms of cache access.

Comment: Question title asks for cache-friendly, question body asks for multithreaded optimization. Make up your mind, those are completely different things.

Comment: @hamstergene Sorry, my bad. I guess I thought it would be ok since the cache is a common bottleneck to multithreading. So that first line is more like, just checking to make sure I should really be wondering about the cache.

Comment: @TonyK: It absolutely wouldn't!

Comment: @Violet What does that mean that vector<bool> is a specialization and what is the implication of that?

Comment: It's stored as a bit-field instead of an array of `bool`s. So there will be more access overhead. But it reduces memory consumption.

Comment: @Mystical Ah, that's good to know. I would definitely like to sacrifice space for access speed. Can I do that conveniently with STL? And will it affect cache misses?

Comment: If you prefer better access speed over memory, then you can use `vector<char>` instead of `vector<bool>`. And yes, increasing memory usage will most likely increase cache misses. Since it's a clear trade-off, you'll need to benchmark it to see whether it still ends up being better.

Comment: @MattMunson: *I'm interested in optimizing my code for multithreaded computing* The question you posted is unrelated to multithreading, but rather to *single core* optimization. If you are really interested in *multithreading*, you should state how you intend on dividing the workload among the threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Case 1** is the most readable.
- **Case 1** and **case 3** are equally cache friendly. Both make only one pass through all the data.*
- **Case 2** is the worst because it makes 4 passes over the data - each pass only touching one element.

If all the struct fields are different, then **case 3** has a huge advantage of possibly being vectorizable while **case 1** doesn't.

The reason for this is because **case 3** is the ***struct of arrays*** packing that puts all the same datatypes together sequentially in memory - thereby exposing vectorization.

**EDIT :**

***Case 3** is potentially even more cache friendly than **case 1** because it doesn't need struct-padding - so the data size is smaller.

Comment: @Mystical cool. Would it matter which order you access the elements in? I thought I heard somewhere that you can move forwards but not  backwards through the cache so that's why I ask.

Comment: As long as it's sequential, it doesn't matter. Processors are able to prefetch both forwards and backwards. (though I'm not aware if it's able to do one direction better than the other)

Comment: Some processors only prefetch forwards. Anyway, there's no point in doing things backwards for no reason! And prefetching is separate from caching. A fetch from memory will always get the whole cacheline whether the first or last word was touched.

Comment: @MattMunson moving backwards are more likely to cause cache missing.

Comment: @Potato So fetching is the process of putting something into the cache right? And then prefetching is putting something into the cache in anticipation? So then some processors only do that the if the memory needed soon is located forward in RAM but not backwards? Is that right?

Comment: Correct on all accounts. But from my experience, every single desktop computer that I've tested is able to prefetch backwards.

Comment: @MattMunson: You should probably read this: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf). Current desktop and server processors, as Mystical points out, are able to prefetch forwards and backwards. The whole cache line will always be pulled, but in a slightly different way depending on whether you access the first, middle or last byte first (i.e. it will try to get first the data that is requested). All these are not (directly) related to multithreading though, but single threaded.

Comment: ... for multithreading there are other factors to take into account, the most important being *sharing* and *false sharing*. If multiple processors access the same data *and* at least one modifies it, it will mark the whole cache line as *modified* and it will have to go back to a slower cache/memory for the other processors to reread. *False sharing* is when the multiple threads do not share data, but they access (and write to) different variables that are placed in the same cache. Again, the line will me marked as *modified* and reread by the other CPUs even if they don't *share* any data.

Comment: @David Thanks for explaining this. I have been hearing about false sharing and suspecting that it is part of the reason my code isn't scaling well up to 16 processors. I'm pretty much just dealing with member vectors where the objects holding them are thread local. But the vector content will still be allocated all to the same heap, and sometimes unfortunately close to other stuff, right? So what can I do about that in terms of sharing and false shearing?

Comment: @MattMunson: 16 processors, 16 cores, or 16 threads? These are all different. You might be maxing out the memory bandwidth, since that is bottlenecked at the memory controller. In that case `vector<bool>` is your friend (it's a true bitvector, i.e. 8 elements per byte of memory) and you should think about ways to compress the dataset further (`short int` or `char` instead of `int`, for starters).

Comment: @Potato oh yeah, i meant cores/threads. Very Interesting about the memory controller. I haven't really come across any references of that as something that I should look into. I suppose memory bandwidth could also be related to cache misses, since you have to fetch new memory at each one. I don't suppose there's a way to profile the memory bandwidth/controller on an HVM virtual machine? Btw, I thought all int, char, etc, were all implemented as 32 or 64 bits because of the way RAM works? does that change when they get moved to the CPU?

Comment: @Matt: Simply put, the memory bus is a pipe which can carry so many GB/s to the CPU. Since you're presumably streaming large quantities of data, you don't need to worry about cache misses… every stream access will be a cache miss, but that's OK. You get so many bytes per second, so make every byte count. It's OK if this implies more computation, because while some threads are crunching data, others will be keeping the memory busy.

Comment: As for profiling, you want something with good CPU access… I don't know much about virtual machine simulation but I think they usually don't cover memory below L2 cache (i.e., cachegrind). Mac OS X Shark and Intel VTune are tools that might help… but you can also manually calculate your GB/s, e.g. using a stopwatch, and compare to your CPU's specs. If you're bottlenecked, it should be a pretty close match.

Comment: @Potato I don't quite follow about the manual profiling. Are you saying that I should benchmark the memory bus max transfer rate and then compare that to a calculation of how much my program is transferring when it's at bottleneck speed?

Comment: From my experience, benchmarking memory bandwidth can be very tricky - especially in NUMA or multi-bank systems where you need to be accessing all nodes or all banks simultaneously to get the maximum bandwidth. In such cases, what you measure via benchmark vs. what you measure in your actual application can vary wildly and will be little indication whether or not you are saturating your bandwidth. One way to measure how bottlenecked you are by bandwidth is to comment out all the computation code (but don't overdo it to where the compiler strips out everything)... Then compare the times.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of cache access, Case 2 is clearly the worst: it will reload memory into cache 4 times.

Case 3 is the same as Case 1 when filling data, but may be worse for later use (assuming that `a b c d` are related and will likely be read together).

This one is even better than case 1:

```
for (vector<something>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
{
    it->a = e1;
    it->b = e2;
    it->c = e3;
    it->d = e4;
}
```

What will be faster depends on many things. For example, computing complex expressions in wrong order may be much worse than any cache misses. You should never make pure theoretical choices without doing real profiling.

Comment: That's why I like C++11's `auto` keyword ;)

Comment: @hamstergene how much quicker is this way? Which step is it cutting out?

Comment: @MattMunson It removes indexing operation (`operator []`).

Comment: But you get back `operator->`, which is equally expensive. (i.e. a trivial address operation which will be done in parallel with the previous memory access.)

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 is best. Case 3 is just as good in terms of cache access, but it has a slight performance overhead from the extra loops. Case 2 is what you have to avoid.

But why don't you run some benchmarks, and let us know the results?

Comment: I'm not going to -1 you, but "slight performance overhead from the extra loops" is not true. Branch prediction and loop unrolling take care of that nicely. It's even possible that the optimizer might have an easier time with shorter loop bodies.